# Max and one-to-many and one-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)


class Model3(models.Model):
    model2 = models.OneToOneField(Model2)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the max among `Model1#model2_set#model3.value`. How can I do that?

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def model2_max_value(self):
        model2_set.
        # for each item in model2_set 
        # get model2_set_item.model3.value
        # and find max among them
```

I thought I could apply `aggregate(Max)` here but couldn't find the way to do it.

Comment: What is `FontFace`? Probably you meant `Model2` in your example?

Comment: @Wtower, typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
max_value = Model3.objects.filter(model2__model1=self).aggregate(Max('value'))
```